# Using Keras Tokenizer to generate n-grams

Tags: nlp, keras, tokenize, text-processing, n-gram

Is it possible to use n-grams in Keras?

E.g., sentences contain in X_train dataframe with "sentences" column.

I use tokenizer from Keras in the following manner:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(lower=True, split=' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train.sentences)
X_train_tokenized = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train.sentences)
```

And later I pad the sentences thus:

```
X_train_sequence = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train_tokenized)
```

Also I use a simple LSTM network:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(MAX_FEATURES, 128))
model.add(LSTM(32, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2,
               activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(64, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(number_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

In this case, tokenizer execution.
In Keras docs: https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/
I see character processing is possible, but that is not appropriate for my case.

My main question: Can I use n-grams for NLP tasks (not only Sentiment Analysis but rather any NLP task)

For clarification: I'd like to consider not just words but combination of words.  I'd like to try and see if it helps to model my task.

Comment: This is a mighty strange NN model you are using there, son

Comment: @VeltzerDoron I am thinking of using bi-grams as well. I am using keras to train a feed forward network using bag of words feature data. So, I'm not using sequence data or a sequence model (RNNs, etc.), so bi-grams make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Keras Tokenizer() does not support n-grams. You should create a workaround and tokenize on your own the documents, and then feed them to the neural network.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not aware, you can use sklearn modules like [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) or [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) to generate n-grams which you can then feed to the network.